# How do I access the return values of ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, threadpool, future

Say I have the following code:

```
def func(a,b):
    return (func2(a),func3(3))

def paralel_func(alist,blist)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        executor.map(func,alist,blist)
```

How do I access the return values that were returned from `func` ? I tried to figure it out myself by thinking that `executor.map` is a list that holds the values but that didnt work for me.

Comment: Where is func2?It is not clear what you really want.

Comment: func2 and func3 are arbitrary non-parallel functions, that return a value
which I'd like to access after I have done my computations

Comment: For what it's worth, if your operation is CPU bound, then you probably don't want to use a thread pool because of Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)

Comment: FYI for those coming here primarily to parallelize I/O tasks, the GIL actually gets released, so @Skam's comment doesn't apply in that case.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know where your alist and blist variables are coming from, but you could do something like this.

```
import concurrent.futures

def func(a, b):
    return (func2(a),func3(3))

def parallel_func(alist, blist):
    processes = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        processes.append(executor.submit(func, alist, blist))
        
        for _ in concurrent.futures.as_completed(processes):
            print('Result: ', _.result())
```

Comment: `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` doesn't return futures, so this approach won't work. See my answer for clarification.

Comment: @knightofiam it's been a while so I'm not sure why I put executor.map in there, but just switching it to executor.submit works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunately your example doesn't compile, and even fixing those errors, it has runtime errors because `submit` doesn't map list elements into function parameters. I'm not sure if you downvoted my answer, but if there's something wrong with it please leave a comment explaining why, thanks.

Comment: @knightofiam There was just a typo. Maybe I pasted something and "import" made it into my with statement. I updated it and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

This answer to a 4 year old question is for posterity, as there seems to be a lot of confusion around python multithreading and correctly obtaining results from worker threads. I know there was for me anyway. So when I figured it out, I wanted to provide a complete answer here that will hopefully help someone else.

First off, you can remove the redundant parentheses from `return (func2(a),func3(3))`. Python knows you're returning a tuple solely from the use of the comma, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple).

Elaborating on @Roland Smith's correct, yet incomplete [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048217/14410393):

`ThreadPoolExecutor.map` returns an `iterator` - of tuples in your case - that may ***evaluate*** your function calls out of order, but will always ***return*** the results in order. While an iterator works well in a for loop to stream single items one-by-one, if you want to collect all the iterator's results into a list, for example, all you have to do is wrap the `iterator` in a `list`:

(Note: Pseudocode, doesn't compile, see full examples further down)

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def func(a, b):
    return func2(a), func3(3)

def paralel_func(alist, blist):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, alist, blist))
        # Print list of tuples, one tuple per line with values separated by commas.
        print('\n'.join(str(x[0]) + ', ' + str(x[1]) for x in results))
```

In your example code, it's not clear what the return types of your two mapped functions, `func2` & `func3` are, whether lists, tuples, single values, etc, but assuming single values, in the above code, `results` will contain a list of tuples. If your return types are integers, the print statement above will convert them to strings.

@NL23codes' answer is a bit misleading because `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` doesn't work with `concurrent.futures.as_completed` because it doesn't return `Future`'s. For that you would want `ThreadPoolExecutor.submit` which is only for one value at a time, so you would need to manually iterate over `alist` & `blist`. I provide a full working example of this below.

@Richard Rublev's answer, while incomplete, provides an insight that one cannot naively iterate over `alist` & `blist` in a nested fashion, as this passes every possible permutation of values from `alist` & `blist` as tuples, resulting in 9 different results, whereas `map` simply passes the first value from `alist` & the first value from `blist` as a tuple, and so on, resulting in 3 different results.  Therefore the correct way to replicate the `map` behavior with `submit` is to use `zip` to combine the two lists before iterating. I provide a full working example of this below.

Notes:

1. I fixed the mispelling of the word "parallel" in `paralel_func`.
2. I changed the `func3(3)` call to `func3(b)` in `func(a, b)`, just for testing purposes, to demonstrate the use of of `b` values.
3. I included example definitions `func2a` & `func2b` for the sake of providing full working examples.

Full working example using `submit` & `zip` with futures:

```
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def func2(a):
    return a + 5


def func3(b):
    return b


def func(a, b):
    return func2(a), func3(b)


def parallel_func(alist, blist):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        processes = []
        for a, b in zip(alist, blist):
            processes.append(executor.submit(func, a, b))
        results = concurrent.futures.as_completed(processes)
        # Print list of tuples, one tuple per line with values separated by commas.
        print('\n'.join(str(x.result()[0]) + ', ' + str(x.result()[1]) for x in results))


parallel_func([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Sample output (notice that `submit` results can be out of order):

```
6, 4
8, 6
7, 5
```

Full working example using `map` without futures:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def func2(a):
    return a + 5


def func3(b):
    return b


def func(a, b):
    return func2(a), func3(b)


def parallel_func(alist, blist):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=None) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(func, alist, blist))
        # Print list of tuples, one tuple per line with values separated by commas.
        print('\n'.join(str(x[0]) + ', ' + str(x[1]) for x in results))


parallel_func([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Sample output (notice that `map` results will always be in order):

```
6, 4
7, 5
8, 6
```

Finally, please note, as @Skam mentioned in his comment on your question, examples like these that are CPU-bound are actually prohibited from being multithreaded due to the Global Interpreter Lock, or GIL. However, if you are trying to parallelize I/O tasks, such as scraping or downloading from websites, the GIL gets released, so this approach can yield very significant speed increases.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should try this

```
ablists = [alist, blist]

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    future_list= {executor.submit(func, a, b): i for i in ablists}
```

You can read more here about [futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) and also executors

Comment: wouldnt I have to loop over `alist` and `blist` to submit the futures ?

Comment: @zython Yes, but not in the typical nested fashion. To emulate `ThreadPoolExecutor.map`, you want to use `zip` to combine the two lists, which will allow you to iterate over the tuples. Please see my answer for clarification.

Comment: Also this example doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

I had some trouble getting the other options to work the way i liked and stumbled across this, which worked well for me.
https://pythonhosted.org/futures/#processpoolexecutor-example

```
import math
from concurrent import futures

PRIMES = [
    112272535095293,
    112582705942171,
    112272535095293,
    115280095190773,
    115797848077099,
    1099726899285419]

def is_prime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    sqrt_n = int(math.floor(math.sqrt(n)))
    for i in range(3, sqrt_n + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for number, prime in zip(PRIMES, executor.map(is_prime, PRIMES)):
            print('%d is prime: %s' % (number, prime))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Incomplete answers that do not show full scope are insuffcient. Where is number, prime and PRIMES defined at?

Comment: Also a definition of `is_prime` would be nice - although it can be inferred - as it stands I find this example a bit confusing because of its lack of context.

Comment: @jrich523 Thanks for updating your answer! Upvoted. It works great, just needs `from concurrent import futures`.

Comment: thanks @knightofiam, it was a copy paste from the link sorta funny they didnt include that, good catch!

Answer (score -1):

The `map` method returns an iterator yielding the results from the calls to `func`.

Comment: Yes this is true and insightful; I also think this would work better as a comment rather than an answer.